# config.GPU = [int(i) for i in config.GPU.split(',')] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: i

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

```
if config.GPU == '-1':
    # Horovod
    torch.cuda.set_device(hvd.local_rank())
    config.GPU = [int(i) for i in range(hvd.size())]
    config.g_lr *= hvd.size()
    config.d_lr *= hvd.size()

else:
    if config.GPU == 'NO_CUDA':
        config.GPU = '-1'
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = config.GPU
    config.GPU = [int(i) for i in config.GPU.split(',')]
    config.batch_size *= len(config.GPU)
    config.g_lr *= len(config.GPU)
    config.d_lr *= len(config.GPU)

torch.manual_seed(config.seed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(config.seed)

config_yaml(config, 'datasets/{}.yaml'.format(config.dataset_fake))
config = cfg.update_config(config)
if config.mode == 'train':
    if hvd.rank() == 0:
        PRINT(config.log, ' '.join(sys.argv))
        _PRINT(config)
    main(config)
    config.log.close()

else:
    main(config)
```

I am getting error in line 'config.GPU = [int(i) for i in range(hvd.size())]'. The error is in the title. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: The code in your title differs from the code in your question.  Please confirm the exact code you are running: the code in your question title will definitely generate that error, and the code in your question may still generate the error depending on what `config.GPU` is.  Please also explain how you are running your code: I wonder if you've edited your code but your old code is still running (e.g. because it's in a web server which you haven't restarted).

Comment: $ python ./main.py --GPU=$gpu_id --dataset_fake=CelebA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 75, in <module>
    config.GPU = [int(i) for i in config.GPU.split(',')]
  File "./main.py", line 75, in <listcomp>
    config.GPU = [int(i) for i in config.GPU.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''                                                                            This is the error that I am getting. I am just running the main file using gitbash. The code is in the users folders.

Comment: Please edit the question to include details like this, rather than posting them as comments.  I note however that your comment contains a different error message to the one in your title, so please edit the title as well.  The next step is for you to investigate what `config.GPU` is.  Add a line such as `print("config.GPU = '{}'".format(config.GPU))` and your code should tell you what it is.  It seems you're expecting this to be a comma-separated list of numbers, but in this case it isn't.

Comment: I would also recommend printing what "config" is (and potentially putting it into the question itself).